# How to add conditional formatting to visualize a increase or decrease based on the previous cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How to add conditional formatting to visualize an increase or decrease based on the previous cell value?  I need to do this to a group of cells. I want to start off with one column of numbers and as the weeks continue I want to visualize how the numbers increase or decrease... see example below.

```
    8-Apr   15-Apr  22-Apr
Team A  5   11  15
Team B  4   3   2
Team C  68  61  75
Team D  2   3   3
Team E  13  15  32
Team F  6   1   11
Team G  22  22  19
```

Comment: This would be better shown in a line graph.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select entire Data Range.
- Reach to **Condition Formatting** then
  **New Rule**.
- Apply Formula and color combinations as
  shown in Screen Shot below.

[image]

*Adjust cell references and color combination as your need.*

## Edited:

If you want to test data in `Col E` and apply Conditional Formatting on `Col F`, as well as want to test `Col F` and apply CF on `Col G` then do this.

- Select either specific Range or entire
  `Column F` and apply these formulas.

`E91>F91` , `E91<F91` & `E91=F91`

Likewise for `Col G` also.

[image]

**N.B.**

*`2014 is Col E` and `2015 is Col F`.*

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as your need.*

Comment: I need it to look at column E and color F if greater/less than or equal, then look at column F and color G if greater/less than or equal, and so on. The only way I have figured it out is to do it for each cell individually and that will be so time consuming as I need this running list each week.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but after selecting the data range to apply your conditional formatting you need to enter your formula based on the active cell in the selection.  I usually tell others to ensure the top left cell is the active cell and then base their formula based on this cell location.

Comment: @ForwardEd, yes Cell `E91` is the left most active cell in the selected range and the formula works accordingly.

Comment: @ESF,, principally for proper data data visualization  user need to get involve entire data range, and you may adjust range selection and the formula accordingly. Also,, If you are stick with `E vs F` and `F vs G` then first you need to select `F` and apply Formula like `E91>F91` and others then select `G` and apply Formula `F91>G91` and others ☺

Comment: @ESF,, now check **edited**  part of my post, it works in the way you are looking for !!